# Choosing tools for animated data visualisation on a google map(or any other map provider).

Tags: google-maps, maps, openlayers, gis

Forgive the vague nature of the query. I wish to make an application to visualize some geographic data on a map. To be clear, I have some lat / long locations in a txt file. I can figure out how to draw them on a map using OpenLayers or the Google Maps API directly. However, I have some other data files, with an attribute related to each point. I would like to iterate over those files , read in the point attributes, and update the map (changing the radius of the respective point) as I read the files. My end goal, is something like what is done here  [World Development Indicator](https://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_&ctype=b&strail=false&nselm=s&met_x=sp_dyn_le00_in&scale_x=lin&ind_x=false&met_y=sp_dyn_tfrt_in&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&met_s=sp_pop_totl&scale_s=lin&ind_s=false&dimp_c=country%3aregion&ifdim=country&iconSize=0.5&uniSize=0.035#!ctype=m&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=s&met_s=sp_pop_totl&scale_s=lin&ind_s=false&ifdim=country&pit=1079478000000&hl=en_US&dl=en_US&ind=false) . 
If someone could explain to me how this is done, or point me to a set of tutorials, I would highly appreciate it. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add all the points as [shape circles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#circles), and store the references in some kind of array or list.

Then you can find the circle and change its radius by the [setRadius(double)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html#setRadius(double)) function.